# How to set CertificateValidationMode on metro style app?

Tags: c#, wcf, certificate, microsoft-metro, nettcpbinding

I have a WCF self hosted service on Azure. I am trying to make a desktop client and a Metro-style App client. I am using nettcpbinding with transport security and a self signed certificate.

On windows 7 this code works :

```
client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
client.GetUpdate(...);
```

but on the metro app the field `ServiceCertificate` doesn't exist, so I'm getting the (expected) exception

```
The X.509 certificate CN=SPDEV-1-PC chain building failed.
The certificate that was used has a trust chain that cannot be verified. 
Replace the certificate or change the certificateValidationMode. 
A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root certificate 
which is not trusted by the trust provider.
```

how do I change the certificateValidationMode ?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem, I solved it with reflection. Try sth. like this:

```
Type credType = typeof (ClientCredential); //enter here type of your credentials
PropertyInfo credPropInfo1 = credType.GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredProperty("ServiceCertificate");
PropertyInfo credPropInfo2 = credPropInfo1.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredProperty("Authentication");
PropertyInfo credPropInfo3 = credPropInfo2.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredProperty("CertificateValidationMode");
credPropInfo3.SetValue(yourObject, 0); // use the int value of the enum, suggested 0 for None
```

Update:
Here some stupid code, that runs fine for me ;)

```
var test6 = client.ClientCredentials.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredProperty("ServiceCertificate").GetValue(client.ClientCredentials);
var test7 = test6.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredProperty("Authentication").GetValue(test6);
test7.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredField("certificateValidationMode").SetValue(test7, 0);
test6.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredField("authentication").SetValue(test6, test7);
client.ClientCredentials.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredField("serviceCertificate").SetValue(client, test6);
```

Comment: I cannot give you the correct code, because I cannot reproduce it. Try to access the Property while you run your program through the immediate window. There are more namespaces available. If you can access it through immediate windows while run time, it is also possible to modify the property with help of reflection.

Comment: I updated the code above. This works for me. An other option is to wait 1-2 weeks and see what Release Preview brings.

Comment: Getting compile error on test8 from the 'var', tried making it a X509CertificateValidationMode but the class doesn't exist ...

Comment: getting an InvalidOperationException "The API 'System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials.get_ServiceCertificate()' cannot be used on the current platform. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248273 for more information." ... link doesn't work unfortunately.